# GET request appearing from nowhere

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, get, django-templates

First of all, excuse me for the title but my problem is very specific and I could'nt find a better title. So I'm currently developing a website using Django and Bootstrap. Since I'm a beginner, I bought a design developed by someone else with bootstrap and I'm adapting it according to my needs.

Here is the full code of the problematic HTML template :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<body class="bg-white">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="d-none d-md-flex col-md-4 col-lg-6 bg-image"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6">
           <div class="login d-flex align-items-center py-5">
              <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-8 mx-auto pl-5 pr-5">
                       <h3 class="login-heading mb-4">Bienvenue !</h3>
                       <form>
                          <div class="form-label-group">
                             <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
                             <label for="inputEmail">Identifiant</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-label-group">
                             <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                             <label for="inputPassword">Mot de passe</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                             <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                             <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Se souvenir de moi</label>
                          </div>
                          <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2">Connexion</a>
                          <div class="text-center pt-3">
                             Vous n'avez pas encore de compte ? <a class="font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'inscription' %}">Inscrivez-vous</a>
                          </div>
                       </form>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Select2 JavaScript-->
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/select2/js/select2.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

In this particular line `<div class="d-none d-md-flex col-md-4 col-lg-6 bg-image"> </div>` I'm trying to display an image.

Here is the associated css code (osahan.css) :

```
.bg-image {
    background-image: url('../media/img_connexion.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

At he beginning, the code was `background-image: url('../img/login-bg.png');` I obviously replace that line with mine in order to display the image I want. The problem is that, when I'm trying to load the web page, I get an error `"GET /static/img/login-bg.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1672` and the image is not displayed. I don't understand where does this GET request come from since the line asking for the login-bg image doesn't exist anymore. I did a research for the term "login-bg" over the whole project and it appears nowhere.
Can someone explain me why my image is not displayed and where does this request come from ?
Thank you in advance !

Note : I tried to display the image directly in the html file with an `<img>` tag and the image is displayed so that is not a problem with the file path or something like that. But I want to use the structure developed by the web designer since it enables the image to fit perfectly the way I want it to fit.

EDIT : 
I used chrome inspector to find the source of the request and here is what I have : 
GENERAL 
`Request URL: http://localhost:8000/static/img/login-bg.png
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade7`

RESPONSE HEADERS 
`Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 21 Dec 2019 17:05:47 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.2
Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

REQUEST HEADERS 
`Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=jXtF8NkGf05cWF3HQiTEgZ8dhjUBwHLc0SB3PjGM5viEzoH7ewi8WFWWZkL4N9Wu
Host: localhost:8000
Referer: http://localhost:8000/static/css/osahan.css
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36`

I guess it's telling me that the osahan.css file is the one responsible for this request but like I said there is nowhere in this file where the term login-bg appears so I'm still stuck with my problem.

EDIT2 : Since I can't find where the request is sent from, I tried renaming my image as "login-bg" and deplacing it in the folder where the request is looking for it. As expected that works and the image is displayed correctly. But then I deleted the image, and the website is still displaying it even if it doesn't exist anymore. I obviously shut down and reload everything and it's still displaying the image... I'm now completely lost, I really don't know how all of this is possible

Comment: Have you already viewed the page source in google chrome or looked at the inspector to find the source of the GET from the browser?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm currently using the inspector to find the source of the request but it's my first time using it and I can't find what I'm searching, can you help me please ?

Comment: If `Referer: http://localhost:8000/static/css/osahan.css` does not have the line in it, tha tprobably means your browser has already cached it.  You can turn off caching in chrome inspector by clicking on the checkbox for "disable cache" in the network tab.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solves the problem ! All my changes where not taken into account due to caching. Thanks a lot mate and have a nice day !